# ¿Cómo prevenir volver a cargar el fragment visible en Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando un menú lateral usando carga de fragments, necesito prevenir la carga del fragment si se está mostrando actualmente, es decir para evitar un duplicado de carga

Actualmente tengo este código para la carga de fragmentos

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
...    
Fragment newFragment = null;
..
newFragment = FragmentHome.newInstance(title,id);
...
newFragment = FragmentSenderos.newInstance(title);

//carga de fragmento
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_layout, newFragment,nameNewFragment)
        .addToBackStack("F_MAIN")
        .commit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solucionado!**, el método siguiente independiente de los fragments cargados o disponibles para cargar.
Solo checkea si el nuevo fragment a cargar, es el mismo que se está visualizando, independiente si ya está cargado o no previamente.

Función loadFragment para cargar un fragmento

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_layout, newFragment,newFragment.getClass().getName())
            .addToBackStack("F_MAIN")
            .commit();
}
```

código para prevenir duplicación de carga del fragmento visible

```
if (newFragment != null) {

    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout);

    if (currentFragment == null) {
        //carga del primer fragment justo en la carga inicial de la app     
        loadFragment(newFragment);
    } else if (!currentFragment.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(newFragment.getClass().getName())) {
        //currentFragment no concide con newFragment
        loadFragment(newFragment);

    } else {
        //currentFragment es igual a newFragment
    }
}
```

En la variable `currentFragment` cargo el fragmento actual del frame layout.
Si `currentFragment` es Nulo, quiere decir que es cuando la app es lanzada por primera vez, se carga el fragment inicial.
Si hay un fragment en el contenedor de fragmentos se compara con el nuevo fragment a cargar `newFragment`.

Answer (score 3):

Como dijo enrique, o podes probar crear una lista donde cada vez que creas un fragment lo agregas a la lista, y cuando ese fragment es destruido lo sacas de la lista.

*Pseudo Codigo*

```
List<Fragment> fragmentosVivos = new List<Fragment>();

//antes de usar tu fragment. preguntas si la lista lo contiene.

if(fragmentosVivos.Contains(fragmentAUsar) == false){
//Usa tu framgento y agregalo a la lista.
 fragmentosVivos.Add(fragmentAUsar);
}
else{
//Fragmento ya activo
}

//....En su onDetach u onDestroy podes sacarlos de la lista

void onDetach(){
fragmentosVivos.Remove(fragment);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, es una solución alternativa del sistema de pila de getSupportFragmentManager que no acabo de comprender ahora mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes revisar si tu fragment ya está presenta en el layout:

```
Fragment mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout);
if (mFragment instanceof FragmentHome) {
    return; // Si el fragment ya existe, regresa
}

// Carga el fragment
```

El operador `instanceof` regresa un valor `boolean` indicando si un objeto es de algún tipo específico.

Comment: Grácias, pero lo que necesito es algo más genérico, que puede servir si tienes dos fragments o más

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar volver a cargar el fragment solo debes agregar un tag al fragment para saber si ya ha sido agregado, este código es útil en el NavigationView para no instanciar de nuevo el fragment si está visible en ese momento.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
    case R.id.navigation_item_0:
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment_contactos");
        if(fragment == null){
           fragment = new FragmentContactos();
           fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment,"fragment_contactos").commit();
        }
     break;
}
```